# Google Maps API for Work and phonegap / cordova

Tags: google-maps, cordova

I bought an API key for Google Map. I tried to implement the client key in a PhoneGap application.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&v=3.17"></script>
```

However, it doesn't work. I have an alert with the message: "your domain is not permitted."
I can't put a domain in the admin console, because it's a phonegap app and the file protocol doesn't work well too.

How can I use the client key with a phonegap app ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Maps Javascript API v3 for work does not work on PhoneGap/Cordova, because the API refers the domain of the page.
You can still use Google Maps Web APIs (direction APIs, geocoding APIs ... etc) with your key.
Ask your Google Maps reseller (or directly Google support team).